# Python lambda function depending on parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability, lambda-calculus

I would like, for convenience, to define several functions as "slices" of a given one, along the following lines:

```
def f(x, k):
    print(x, k)


gs = []
for k in range(2):
    gs.append(lambda x: f(x, k))
```

But now I get

```
gs[0]('a') == ('a', 1)
gs[1]('a') == ('a', 1)
```

I would like to get:

```
gs[0]('a') == ('a', 0)
gs[1]('a') == ('a', 1)
```

I understand why I get the previous thing, and wonder if there is some standard way of obtaining the latter; in some sense I want to "freeze" the immutable value of `k` upon declaration of the lambda function.